# How to run one server docker container before client container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I have a fairly complex application where I have next js on the client and on the backend I have graphql and I have nginx as a reverse proxy.

I am using next JS incremental static site regeneration functionality on the index page so that's why I want my server up and running before my client container start building because when I run npm run build it is going to fetch some data from the graphql server here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  mynginx:
    container_name: mynginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80

  graphql:
    container_name: graphql_server
    depends_on:
      - mynginx
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  mynextjs:
    container_name: nextjs_server
    depends_on:
      - graphql
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: You can use depends_on key https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on

Comment: I'm not clear this approach will work: a Docker image build is never attached to any particular Docker network, and it won't be able to contact your server, even if it does start first.  If "static" pages will be incrementally built by fetching from the server container at runtime, can you avoid generating anything at all at build time?

Comment: Just let the client fail, but set `restart=always`. The clients will continue to die until the server is ready, and only the last one will survive. This is the preferred approach.

Comment: @Prince Tanwar, I am facing the same problem, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

`depends_on` with `healthcheck`, to start container when another already works

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck

something like this

```
services:
  mynginx:
    container_name: mynginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -O /dev/null http://localhost || exit 1"]
      timeout: 10s

  graphql:
    ...
    depends_on:
      depends_on:
        mynginx:
          condition: service_healthy
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, what you need is to wait until `graphql` service is properly finished starting before you run `mynextjs` service.

I'm afraid that `depends_on` (or `links`) might not work out of the box in this case. The reason is, although Compose does start `graphql` service before it starts `mynextjs` service, it doesn't wait until `graphql` service is in READY state to start the dependant services.

Basically, what you need is to find a way to tell Compose to wait until `graphql` service is in READY state.

The solution is described in [Control startup and shutdown order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order) in Compose documentation

I hope this helps you. Cheers  !!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to delay beginning the build of the image for the frontend container, until the backend containers are running and ready.

The easiest way that comes to mind would be to use profiles to allow starting these independently.

Eg:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mynginx:
    container_name: mynginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    profiles: ["backend"]

  graphql:
    container_name: graphql_server
    depends_on:
      - mynginx
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    profiles: ["backend"]

  mynextjs:
    container_name: nextjs_server
    depends_on:
      - graphql
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    profiles: ["frontend"]
```

Then chain the starting something like:

```
docker-compose --profile backend -d up && docker-compose --profile frontend -d up
```

Another option might be splitting into two separate compose files, with a shared docker network between them.

ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Comment: this  "docker-compose --profile backend -d up && docker-compose --profile frontend -d up"  command is not working